# Mock on input to a function in java

Tags: java, mockito

Let's say we have a function which takes input as a class object `obj`. can we mock call made from `obj` ?

For example:

```
Class Library {
   public int methodA (Book obj) {
         int x = obj.getPages(); 
         return x+1;
  }
}

Class Book {
   int x = 10;
   public int getPages(){
      return x;
   }
}
```

I am writing the test case for methodA

```
@InjectMock 
Library library;

@Test
public void testMethodA () {

   // mock the respnse of obj.getPages() call. 

   int x = library.methodA();

}
```

Is there any way to mock the response of `obj.getPages()`

Comment: You're passing in the object to the call-it can do whatever you want as long as it's a Book.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `Book` object instead of mocking it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to mock just `getPages()` method, you don't need to mock `Library`, just `Book`. Do like this:

```
Library library = new Library();
Book obj = Mockito.mock(Book.class);

Mockito.when(obj.getPages()).thenReturn(1); // return 1 or whatever value you want

int x = library.methodA(obj);
```

`methodA()` will call `obj.getPages()`, which will return whatever value you configured in `thenReturn()`

Comment: No, I can not use setter method. I want to mock only.

Comment: No problem, you can use the code I suggested above. I'm gonna remove the setter part of the answer